# How to resolve the errors "cannot find symbol" and "')' expected"?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

```
package com.mycompany.sockettest;

/**
 *
 * @author 11ede
 */
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
        


public class newClient {
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final int SERVER_PORT = 9095;
    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
        
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        
        String serverReponse = input.readLine();
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( parentComponent null, serverResponse);
        
        socket.close();
        System.exit(status 0);

    }
}
```

The bottom two lines have been underlined in netbeans i'm not sure whats going on. It says in the hint the variable 'status' is to blame on the last line and on the line just above the socket.close , it says the symbol cannot be found again. Also says a ';' is to be expected but there is already one.

Comment: When calling a method you only need to pass the values as in `System.exit(0);` or `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, serverResponse);` Adding the parameter name in front of it like `status 0` or `parentComponent null` is neither necessary nor allowed.

Comment: You're missing a comma after `parentComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare your variables. `status`, `parentComponent`, and `serverResponse` need to be declared first in order to be used. With the method you are using, `parentComponent` needs to be of type `Component` and `serverResponce` needs to be an `Object`. `status` just needs to be an `int`. You can't declare them in the methods themselves when you are calling them.